# Why $() doesn't work but jQuery() works?

Tags: jquery

I have an issue where `$("#register") returns null`, but `jQuery("#register")` returns object correctly.

This may be worth thousand words:

[image: Chrome inspector expressing the problem]

As you can see in Watch expression everything works as expected (`jQuery === $ returns true`)
But in console it doesn't. And in code it also doesn't, because the `$("#register").validate` string doesn't work.

Maybe it has to do something with [$script.js](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs) thing?

Comment: Are you using multiple frameworks?

Comment: maybe you have some function `$()`

Comment: The issue is now solved - i think its Chrome's Web Inspector thing that overrides $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to return in 5 minutes and say that the code works. Uh.

It's just that $ is something the web inspector overrides.

The $script.js doesn't cause conflicts.

```
> jQuery.noConflict()
function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)}
> $
function ()
    {
        return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments)
    }
```

It's the chrome inspector problem :)

Comment: @PrAtikLochawala Solve what? It only gets in a way when you use Chrome Dev tools. It has it's own meaning for $ variable: [$(selector) docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector). If you call jQuery.noConflict(), you can assign it to other variable and use that variable instead of $ so it doesn't conflict with chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe some other javascript framework that you are using hijacks the `$()` function. You may take a look at [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for tips about using jQuery with other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrectly written jQuery plugin may be cause of this problem

Answer (score 1):

It happens because both JavaScript files declare function $

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid any possible conflicts, prior to using jQuery, you need to call `jQuery.noConflict();`.  Afterwards, use "jQuery" object on the base script level whenever you need to use it, though internal to any such method you can use $ rather than jQuery.

In other words, you should write:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.ready(function() {
    // do stuff
    $('#btn').button();
});
```

Notice that inside ready, I can use $ again without worrying about other conflicts.