# jQuery document.ready not prepending

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, prepend, lightbox2

I have noticed that document.ready not prepending `<div>` tag.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var shadow = $('<div id="shadowElem"></div>');
    var speed = 1000;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').prepend(shadow);
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

*- In console, There are no errors.*

This is truly frustrating now and any help will be really appreciated.

~ Dipak G.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Just tried. Does't work :(

Comment: your same code working fine in my browser 
here is the [working link](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/cxn6apms/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:-

```
 var shadow = jQuery('<div id="shadowElem"></div>');    
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').prepend(shadow);
 });
```

for more information check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510589/why-doesnt-work-but-jquery-works) link

Comment: This did the trick. However if you check http://success-insights.co.uk , it displays popup but some elements in background still appears ( http://awesomescreenshot.com/0743hitw93 ). Any thoughts? Thanks mate.

Comment: @DipakG. give z-index:9999 to css class `#shadowElem`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that problem is in document.ready().
Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
$('body').prepend('<div id="shadowElem">Test</div>');
});
```

Comment: The prepend() method inserts specified content at the beginning of the selected elements. It will not add element before body tag!

Comment: @andrey.shedko your code works but the information you are providing in your P.S. is not correct. Check your working code in developer tool by changing to prepend(), it displays the div added inside the body tag.

Comment: @VaibhavKatole. I will delete P.S. in order do not confuse anyone with it.

Comment: @andrey.shedko that's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a conflict with prototype.js and jQuery. You may need to try  jQuery.noConflict();
I would suggest using one library instead of both. Of course you will need to use a jquery lightbox instead, from what I see on your link.